# AngularJS Dynamically displaying the multiple records

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

Below is my AngularJS Code. I'm adding four records to `roleList`. But I want to add N number of records to `roleList`. How can I achieve this.

```js
$scope.roleList = [
    {"companyName": "Company 01", "id":"1", "position": "CEO"},
    {"companyName": "Company 02", "id":"2", "position": "Board of Director"},
    {"companyName": "Company 01", "id":"1", "position": "CEO"},
    {"companyName": "Company 02", "id":"2", "position": "Board of Director"}

];
```

Comment: Can you please tell more in detail?

Comment: `$scope.roleList.push(record)` will add record

Comment: $scope.lines = [];
// For loop start //
  $scope.roleList.push( {"companyName": "Company 02", "id":"2", "position": "Board of Director"});
// For loop end //

Will it work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you make a `for`?

```
var limit=100;
var roleList=[];
for(var i=0;i<limit;i++){
   roleList.push({
     companyName:'some name', 
     id:i,
     position:'some position'
   });
}
$scope.roleList=roleList;
```

Comment: Thanks Kosmo. This is exactly im looking